# weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory

Tags: spring, weblogic, classpath, saaj

I am stuck with the following error when I deploy my web-services client application in weblogic. [This application has been working without any issues in tomcat.]

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'saajSoapMessageFactory' while
>   setting constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'saajSoapMessageFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [.../core/ws/ws-config.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not
>   create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create message factory for SOAP:
>   weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory; nested exception is
>   javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create message factory for
>   SOAP: weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast
>   to javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory

Here is the bean definition in ws-config.xml

```
(bean id="saajSoapMessageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory")
```

I tried searching for this issue, but unfortunately could not find any solution. Am I missing anything in the spring config? Has any one faced this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not come across this - but what's happening is that Weblogic uses it's own default for the MessageFactoryImpl

Check your weblogic startup logs and you will see some parameters set such as

```
javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory = weblogic.webservice.core.rpc.ServiceFactoryImpl
javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory = weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl
```

You can try 2 options (I dont know which will work, try it out)

A)

In your client, set these yourself to the Spring equivalents

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory",      "org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory");
System.setProperty( "javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory",      "** Spring version **");
```

B) Pass your required version as a `-D` parameter in the startWeblogic.cmd

`-Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory`

and add saaj jars to the weblogic classpath.

Comment: Including the saaj jars(saaj-impl and saaj-api) in the classpath helped resolve this issue. Previously I had not included these jars as part of the WS client application (deployed in weblogic) and weblogic had used "weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl" as the message factory which had caused this issue.