# Java/Coldfusion Weblogic error

Tags: java, soap, coldfusion, weblogic

I have a .jar which is accessed to create signed SOAPs by ColdFusion, this works fine when I run it on my local host, however when I run it on the server (Weblogic) it gives me the error:

"**Unable to create message factory for SOAP: weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl**"

Unfortunately I don't have access to poke around in Weblogic all I can do is pass over .jar and .cfm files to be used.

Since this works fine locally I assume it is some other external dependency that I am missing, or a different version of a dependency is being run, but I have no idea how I can go about fixing it.

(I have already tried this: [weblogic.webservice.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210702/weblogic-webservice-core-soap-messagefactoryimpl-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-xml-soa) )

Comment: Better suited for ServerFault

Comment: Did you have the right webservices JAR file in the right place?

Comment: @ScottStroz I put it here because I have no access to the server, so I do not want server answers, I want answers relating to the Java code and Coldfusion Code.

Comment: @COLINHY I have replicated the JAR location that I am using on my test server which works fine.

Comment: Good! Nice to hear it worked for you.